# Join Date and Time to DateTime in VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am retrieving data from DB where there is a separate date and time fields. I want to join them into a DateTime field in my VB.NET project.
How would you suggest accomplishing this?

I tried this but it's not working for me.
"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

```
Dim InDate As New DateTime(incident.IncidentDate.Value.Year, incident.IncidentDate.Value.Month, incident.IncidentDate.Value.Day, 0, 0, 0)
                    Dim InTime As New DateTime(1900, 1, 1, incident.IncidentTime.Value.Hour, incident.IncidentTime.Value.Minute, incident.IncidentTime.Value.Second)


                    Dim combinedDateTime As DateTime = DateTime.Parse((InDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + " " + InTime.ToString("hh:mm tt")))

                    rdtpIncidentDateTime.SelectedDate = combinedDateTime
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can just create a new `DateTime` value from the components in `InDate` and `InTime`:

```
Dim combinedDateTime As DateTime = New DateTime( _
  InDate.Year, InDate.Month, InDate.Day, _
  InTime.Hour, InTime.Minute, InTime.Second _
)
```

Comment: @MarkZukerman: Good point, I intentionally left them out as the source data doesn't have any milliseconds in it. (If you use it, it would go as another parameter after the seconds.)

Comment: thupped because you ended the line with a semicolon (no fair anybody editing it out)

Comment: @FastAl: Thanks for spotting that. I wrote code mainly in C#, so sometimes some things creep in when I write VB code.

Answer (score 8):

DateTime exposes a method called [DateTime.TimeOfDay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday(v=vs.110).aspx)

You can simply use [DateTime.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.add(v=vs.110).aspx) to append the time to the date.

```
Dim dateAndTime As DateTime = myDate.Add(myTime.TimeOfDay)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim CombinedDate As Date = Date1.Date + Time1.TimeOfDay
```

This will work when you want to combine the DATE from one variable and the TIME from a different variable.

Date is an alias to DateTime.  In VB.NET, they are the same thing. You can see all the aliases in this chart on MSDN.  [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/index)

Comment: Thank you that was very helpful. My issue was to retrieve Date from Field1 and Time From Field2 from a database table to a DateTimePicker placed on a WinForm.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it in one line...declare your indate and use the incident values for the time instead of zeros.